# Treat symbols as elements of a non-commutative field

Tags: linear-algebra, symbolic, expression-manipulation, inverse

I want to invert a matrix, `{{a,b},{c,d}}`, where `a,b,c,d` are elements of a non-commutative field (for example invertible matrices).  However when I use the function `Inverse`, it outputs elements as $\dfrac{d}{da-bc}$, while I actually need $(da-bc)^{-1} d$.

Is there a way to specify in *Mathematica* that `a,b,c,d` should be treated as elements of a non-commutative field?

Comment: I think you'll have to write your own `NoncommutativeInverse` function.

Answer (score 4):

The package [NCAlgebra](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC) does exactly what you are looking for.

Example:

```
NCInverse[{{a, b}, {c, d}}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Result matrix]